# Scandit 4.8.1 cause cordova to fail on eclipse

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

Cordova: 5.0, eclipse: Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

When I add the scandit plugin from scandit-barcodescanner-community-phonegap_4.8.1

The ecplise cannot run the app any more with the following msg in console:

```
warning: string 'menu_settings' has no default translation.
res/raw/beep.wav:0: error: Resource entry beep is already defined.
res/raw/beep.ogg:0: Originally defined here.
```

I actually need this plugin only for ios, please help